# Strange behaviour default string compare with underscores

Tags: c#, stringcomparer

Normally if a character A is smaller than character B, then I'd expect in string comparison:

```
AB < BA
```

And indeed, in a dictionary you can find AB words before BA words.

Somehow this is not the case for underscores

Small program; use copy paste to check

```
public static void Main()
{
    IComparer<string> comp = Comparer<string>.Default;
    Console.WriteLine("Compare '-' with '_': " + comp.Compare("-", "_").ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Compare '--' with '-_': " + comp.Compare("--", "-_").ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Compare '-_' with '_-': " + comp.Compare("-_", "_-").ToString());
}
```

The output is:

```
Compare '-' with '_': -1
Compare '--' with '-_': -1
Compare '-_' with '_-': 1
```

**The last value returns +1**
So:

```
"-"< "_"              // minus is less than underscore
"-_" > "_-"           // minus underscore MORE THAN underscore minus
```

This behaviour occurs when using the default string comparer. StringComparer.Ordinal works as expected.

Is this an error in the default string comparer?

Comment: This behavior is culture-specific ([demo](https://ideone.com/4DfXBF)).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight then probably we wrongly marked that as duplicate?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight on the other hand - site you linked uses gmcs compiler (stated on the right), which is mono compiler, so that might be the difference and not culture. I tried on .NET (not mono) with "en-us" culture (used at site you linked) - and it produces the same results as in question.

Comment: @Evk I tried this on my Mac using MS Dev Studio community edition, and I get the same results as on ideone. Mac's version uses mono, so I think you're right about it being mono-vs-microsoft implementation difference.

Comment: In which culture is minus before underscore, but "minus underscore" after "underscore minus" in the dictionary?